# Optimize oracle query with IN clause

Tags: java, sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have two queries where I am using in parameter and I am populating the `PreparedStatement` using `setLong` and `setString` operations.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT A, B FROM TABLE1 WHERE A in  (SELECT A FROM TABLE2 WHERE C in (?,?,?) )
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT A, B FROM TABLE1 WHERE A in (?,?)
```

I am being told that it creates a unique query for each possible set size and pollutes Oracle's SQL cache. Also, oracle could choose different execution plans for each query here as size is not fixed.

What optimizations could be applied to make it better?

Would it be fine if I create in-clause list of size 50 and populate remaining ones using dummy/redundant variables?

If I am not wrong, select-statement in the in-clause will be difficult to optimize unless it is extracted out and used again as a list of statements.

Comment: How about executing those queries separate, obtaining the result of first query, append the results into `StringBuilder` to then send it as parameter of the other query? This is optimizable by your database engine.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That would be worse, because now the query cache would contain a copy for each unique set of parameters, not merely for each length of `IN` list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am being told that it creates a unique query for each possible set size and pollutes Oracle's SQL cache.

This is correct, assuming that the number of items in the `IN` list can change between requests. If the number of question marks inside the `IN` list remains the same, there would be no "pollution" of the cache.

> Also, oracle could choose different execution plans for each query here as size is not fixed.

That is correct, too. It's a good thing, though.

> What optimizations could be applied to make it better? Would it be fine if I create in-clause list of size 50 and populate remaining ones using dummy/redundant variables?

Absolutely. I used this trick many times: rather than generating a list of the exact size, I generated lists of length divisible by a certain number (I used 16, but 50 is also fine). If the size of the actual list wasn't divisible by 16, I added the last item as many times as it was required to reach the correct length.

The only optimization this achieves is the reduction of items in the cache of query plans.

Comment: So you mean that is better to repeat elements in the `IN` clause just to maintain the same number of arguments in the query cache of the db engine? If that's so, is very clever.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I didn't invent this trick - I "borrowed" it from a group of engineers who quit Oracle to work at our startup. This was more than 15 years ago, so I am not sure if the speed gains are as relevant now as they were in the late nineties. Since the amount of memory that RDBMS can allocate for its cache went up several times, I would expect the trick to have smaller impact today.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In terms of performance, how would oracle behave if I keep giving 50 of inputs instead of 4-5 in the case when same 4-5 values are repeated?

Will it cause any performance issue?

Comment: @instanceOfObject It didn't in my benchmarks. However, I did my benchmarking more than a decade ago, when a gigabyte of memory on a RDBMS server was considered a lot of memory. Back then, a cost of kicking out a plan from the cache was higher than the cost of processing the same value up to 15 times. It would probably be true now as well, except that you need a lot more queries for the cache to start kicking out existing query plans.

Comment: Not sure, if I missed....but even then (and roughly, now as well), would it be (have been) more intensive to optimize cache size and putting redundant value?

I mean, could "select A from T where A in (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1...50 times)" be more expensive (on an average) than random "select A from T where A in (X no of times)" where X are unique?

Comment: @instanceOfObject Back then, and now, the database engine can (and will) eliminate duplicates in extremely short time by using a hash table. Even with fifty values this wastes very little time. On the other hand, missing out on a pre-built query plan forces DB engine to run optimizer again, which is a lot slower than fifty hash lookups, even for the simplest of SQL queries. The only difference between then and now is how often a cache miss happens. With larger cache of query plans you get fewer misses, so in the long run, this optimization becomes less important.